# Android : Adding space in between tab layout

Tags: java, android, tabs

I am working on an Android project in which I am using TabLayout to show tabs as shown in the image below. As you can see in the screenshot, the tabs are all aligned on the left side. How can I add spaces properly so the three tabs fill out the entire width instead of getting clubbed in on left side. Thank you.

Screenshot :

[image]

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fillViewport="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="Search...."
        android:textColor="@color/nliveo_black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/nliveo_black"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/search"
        android:layout_above="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/xblack"
        android:layout_above="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/productList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout3" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trashImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
            android:src="@drawable/swappossible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/swapImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trashImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/footerheart" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/swapImage"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
            android:src="@drawable/footermessages" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
public class Products extends Activity{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.products);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tinder"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("List"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Maps"));
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                switchIntentsForTabs(tab.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switchIntentsForTabs(tab.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
            }
        });
}
```

PageAdapter.java :

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FirstTab();
            case 1:
                return new SecondTab();
            case 2:
                return new ThirdTab();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

FirstTab.java :

```
public class FirstTab extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

tab_fragment_1.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    // Tried adding layout_marginLeft=150 in TextView below, nothing changed.
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add TabLayout coding

Comment: @vinoth12594 : Main post edited, kindly have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @vinoth12594 : the first xml in the post is the products layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove below line in your activity file

```
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

and Change your tablayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fillViewport="false" />
```

Comment: Yes, the last edit made the correct change. Now it works nice. Thank you boss!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int a= 0; a< tabLayout.getTabCount(); a++) {           
    View tabView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), R.layout.item_main_tabview, null, false);

    tabView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tabView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(a).setCustomView(tabViewBinding.getRoot());
}
```

Thus You can add space between tabs in tablayout